# Warning:You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword

Tags: c#, unity3d, warning

Постоянно вываливается предупреждение:

```
You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor()
ObjectDataBase:.ctor()
```

Это из-за этих строк в коде :

```
ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
```

Полностью код:

```
...
public class PlacementObjects : EditorWindow
{
    ObjectDataBase ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
    ...
    void OnEnable()
    {
        ...
        ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
        ...
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        string[] tabs = { "Объекты", "Назначение/Просмотр DATA у Terrain", "TAB THREE" };
        //selectedTab = GUILayout.Toolbar(selectedTab, tabs, tabStyle);
        selectedTab = GUILayout.Toolbar(selectedTab, tabs);
        switch (selectedTab)
        {
            case 0:
                DrawLayouts();
                DrawHeader();
                DrawLeft();
                DrawRight();
                DrawFooter();
                break;
            case 1:
                DrawListTerrain();
                break;
            case 2:
                GUILayout.Label("TAB THREE");
                break;
        }
        EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck();
    }

    void SetGamObjArrayPrefab(int Objint)
    {
        ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
        ...
    }
    void InitOnGUI()
    {
        ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
        ...
    }
    void DrawHeader()
    {
        ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
        ...
    }
    void SaveInBDObj(string stringupdate)
    {
        ODBtemp = new ObjectDataBase();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Как лучше переписать код , чтоб предупреждения не было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, Ваш класс `ObjectDataBase` наследуется от `MonoBehaviour`. А **корректно создавать** новые экземпляры компонентов можно только методом `AddComponent`.

Отсюда два решения:

**1.  Создавать ObjectDataBase в каком-нибудь объекте-контейнере**

```
ODBtemp = gameObjectParent.AddComponent<ObjectDataBase>();
```

**2. Переписать класс ObjectDataBase без наследования от MonoBehaviour**

<...>